# Expresión con una subselect

Tags: mysql

Tengo que hacer el siguiente ejercicio:
¿Cuál  es  el  importe  total  de  los  pedidos  realizados  por  el  empleado Vicente Pantalla?. Hacerlo  con subselect.

Sé sacarlo a través de inner join, pero con subselect no veo la manera. No consigo pensar en la forma de llegar al resultado. Agradecería si alguien me echa un cable.

Os dejo el modelo entidad relación de la base de datos:

[image: Diagrama Entidad-Relaación]

Gracias.

Pd: se me olvidaba.

Como he comentado he conseguido, creo, sacarlo con joins:

```
select e.nombre, sum(l.importe) total
from empleado e
join cliente on NumEmp = REPCLIE
join pedido p on NUM_CLIE = cliente 
join lineaspedido l on p.NUMPEDIDO = l.NUMPEDIDO
where e.NOMBRE = "Miguel Moreno"
group by 1;
```

Comment: En lugar de enlaces coloca la imagen justo aquí

Comment: ¿Así está bien?

Gracias por el consejo!

Comment: ¿Cómo indentificas que pedido fue realizado por X empleado, al menos no veo algo que vincule a los pedidos con los empleados?

Comment: Hago la unión de los clientes con sus representantes (que son los empleados). Luego la unión de los clientes con sus pedidos (Ya tendríamos los pedidos que han hecho cada empleado, ¿no? y luego uno los pedidos con sus líneas de pedido.

Comment: Igual y estoy diciendo un disparate, pero me parece mal diseñada ya que si tenemos que un clinte puede hacer varios pedidos entonces varios empleados pueden gestionar varios pedidos, por lo que ¿la relación no debería ser muchos a muchos?, segundo ¿por qué la tabla de empleados resguarda una columna llamada couta?, dudo que dicha columna tenga que ver con la entidad empleados; pero igual espera comentarios de otros usuarios

Comment: Bueno, hay que tener en cuenta, que quizás debí decirlo antes, es una base de datos de prueba, diseñada así para poder hacer ciertas consultas de un boletín de ejercicios que nos ha dado nuestra profesora.

Hay muchas cosas que podrían mejorar, pero está diseñada de esa forma, para complicar las consultas, entre otros motivos.